# Forbid access to directory except only one subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a following dir structure on file system:

`/users/[uid1]/`

`/users/[uid2]/` etc. (UID part is dynamic in the url, like `/users/abc123/` or `/users/def456/`)

Inside of uid-dirs I also have some subdirectories and files for example:
`images-dir` `another-dir` `file1` `file2`

I also have a .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L,QSA]
```

So I rewrite every request to index.php for routing, only if requested file doesn't exist on file system.

Can I somehow forbid access to  `/users/[uid]/*` except `images-dir`?

For example, allow:

`/users/123abc/images-dir/some-image.jpg`

and deny :

`/users/123abc/another-dir`

`/users/123abc/file1`

I need to deny direct access to this sub directories AND if somebody tries to get contents of forbidden files I want to send request to index.php

Is it possible to do with .htaccess?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a single `.htaccess` file in the document root.

You could do something like the following before your existing directives:

```
# If the request maps to a file or directory in the /users/<uid> space
# But is not the "images-dir" then forbid access
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/\w+/images-dir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^users/\w+/ - [F]
```

`\w+` matches the `<uid>` and includes alphanumeric and underscore characters. If the `<uid>` follows a specific format then you could be more specific here.

If you only reference static resources in the `/users/<uid>/...` space (ie. no virtual URLs) then you could remove the above filesystem checks, since you know that every request targets a filesystem resource.